# OpenShift Options +Indexes still do not work

Tags: .htaccess, openshift

When I place `Options +Indexes` in `.htaccess` I always get 404 instead of [DirectoryListings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings). However this [wasn't](https://forums.openshift.com/options-indexes-in-htaccess-file) always possible [now it should be](https://openshift.uservoice.com/forums/258655-ideas/suggestions/6291445-allow-apache-autoindexing). But I can't get it working.

I have a folder of images which I need to get listed. I'm using the perl-5.10 cartridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options +Indexes is disabled on OpenShift due to security risks.  It can not be enabled by the user.

Comment: Well, knowing this before I would save myself a lot of headaches. Anyway, thank you.